# Actionscript/Air - possible to check email

Tags: email, actionscript, air

Is it possible to check POP email from an air application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS3 has sockets, so in theory you could write your own implementation of the protocol.

However, it appears you may be spared of that torture as there is at least one implementation out there: http://code.google.com/p/airxmail/.